# Equivalence in strong convergence of operators

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces

I am trying to see if I have that $(T_n)\in L(X)$ bounded and that $T_nx$ converges to $Tx$ for every $x$ in a dense subset of $X$ a Banach space, then $T_n$ converges strongly to $T$.

Let suppose that $D$ is the dense subset, I was able to see that if $x\in cl D$ then $T_nx$ is a Cauchy sequence so we know that it converges , but I can't see that it converges to $T_x$. Also I tried seeing by this '$$||T_nx-T_x||=||T_nx-T_nd_n+T_nd_n-T_x||\leq ||T_n||||x-d_n||+||T_nd_n-T_x||,$$ where $d_k \rightarrow x,$ but I can't seem to prove what I want. Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Case 1:** $\sup_n\|T_n\|=\infty.$ Then your assertion need not be true. For example Let $X=c_0, D=c_{00}$ and $T_n(x)=(x_1,2x_2,3x_3,\ldots,nx_n,0,0,\ldots)$ for $x \in X.$ Then $\|T_n\|=n \to \infty$ which means $T_n$ cannot converge strongly in $X.$ However $T_n x \to 0$ for every $x \in D.$

**Case 2:** Suppose $M:=\sup_n\|T_n\|<\infty.$
Since $T \in L(D,X),$ so by Lemma below it has a unique *norm preserving* extension $T \in L(X).$ Then $\|T\|\leq M.$

Let $x \in X.$ Since $D$ is dense in $X,$ there exists $(x_k)$ in D such that $x_k \to x.$ Let $\epsilon >0,$ then there exists $k_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $$\|x_{k_0}-x\|<\frac{\epsilon}{3M}.$$ By given condition $T_n x_{k_0} \to T x_{k_0}$. Therefore there exists $n_0\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $$\|T_nx_{k_0}-Tx_{k_0}\|<\frac{\epsilon}{3}$$ for all $n \geq n_0.$ Combining

$$\begin{align*}\|T_n x-Tx\|&\leq \|T_n x-T_n x_{k_0}\|+\|T_nx_{k_0}-Tx_{k_0}\|+\|Tx_{k_0}-Tx\|\\&<M \frac{\epsilon}{3M}+\frac{\epsilon}{3}+M\frac{\epsilon}{3M}\\&=\epsilon\end{align*}$$ for all $n \geq n_0.$

**Lemma:** Let $X:$ normed space, $Y:$ Banach space, $D \subseteq X:$ dense and $T_0 \in L(D,Y).$ Then there exists a *unique* $T \in B(X,Y)$ such that $T\mid_D=T_0$ and $\|T\|=\|T_0\|.$

Comment: The last part where you write $Tx_{k0}-Tx$ I have a question, you claim to take $T$ the unique norm preserving extension and with that I can understand why the claim would be true, but what if we dont know anything about $T$? And dont know if he is bounded at $x \in X-D$? That's the part of the argument that I am missing.Or do we need that $T$ has to be this unique norm preserving extension , maybe because the space is hausdorff?

Comment: @Something I have edited my answer. The proof of the Lemma can be found in any standard texts on Functional Analysis. For instance, see Lemma 2.13 [here.](http://www.math.kit.edu/iana3/~schnaubelt/media/fa17-skript.pdf)

Comment: Yes that makes sense but how do you know that $T\in L(D,Y)?$? Don't you need that the space is complete or something? At least I think we would need to use something like the uniform boundedness principle.@Sahiba Arora

Comment: @Something Note that in the statement of the lemma, $Y$ is a Banach space. Also, space $X$ in your question was Banach, so you can apply the lemma.

Comment: Sorry I am talking about this after a long time but I started looking at this again and I have a question that is if we don't assume that we are working the unique extension of the operator to a continuous operator in $L(X)$ we can't be sure about this right because we have no way to dominate the term in the part about $||T||$ in $X/D$?@Sahiba Arora

Comment: @LizardKing It is an easy exercise to show that the extension must be unique using the density of $D.$ In fact, it is also shown in Lemma 2.13 in the link I provided in one of my earlier comments.

Comment: Yes I know that the extension is unique if it is bounded , but what I was trying to say is that if we do not assume that the extension is bounded in $X/D$ we don't get the result

Comment: @LizardKing The Lemma doesn't assume the extension is bounded. It **asserts** that the extension is bounded. The assumption is $T_0 \in L(D,Y).$

Comment: Yes I am not questioning the Lemma what I am saying is that when doing this we assume we wanted the unique continuous extension , but there may be other extensions that are not continuous  on $X/D$ for which this doesn't work right ?@Sahiba Arora

Comment: @LizardKing You wanted to show strong convergence of $T_n$ on $X.$ The limit is **the** unique norm preserving extension of $T\in L(D, X).$ When a sequence converges, the limit is unique. So of course if you pick a linear operator $S:X \to X$ different from the extension, then $T_n \not\to S.$ It is natural to expect that if $T_n$ converges to $T$ on a dense subspace, it would converge to its norm preserving extension on the whole space. This is not something we assume. We believe intuitively it is true and then we actually prove it.

Answer (score 2):

This is not true. Let $X=\ell^{2}$ and $D=\ell^{0}$ (the space of sequences that have only finite number of non-zero terms). Then $D$ is dense in $X$. Let $T=0$ and  $T_n(x=(0,0,...,0,nx_n,(n+1)x_{n+1},...,2nx_{2n},0,0,...)$. Then $T_n x\ \to Tx$ for all $x \in D$ but $T_nx$ does not tend to $Tx$ when $x=(1,\frac 1 2, \frac 1 3 ,...)$.

Of course, you argument works if $\|T_n\|$ is bounded.